# Angular ui router not redirecting with $location.path()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to define in the `run` method of my module some simple route security.

But what ever I try, I get redirected to secure route although I'am not logged in:

```
            // Secure routes
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                if ("login" === toState.name) {
                    return;
                }

                let authorized = toState.data ? toState.data.authorization : false;

                if (!securityService.isAuthenticated && authorized !== true) {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            });
```

I tried `$location.path("/login");`, `$location.url("/login");`,  `window.location.href = "/login";`, also I tried `$rootScope.$apply` etc. Nothing of those could make me redirect to login page.

**EDIT: more detailed view**

```
namespace testWeb {
    class AppComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
        template = `
        <div class="root"><div ui-view=""></div>
        </div>`;
        controller = AppController;
    }

    interface IAppController {
    }

    export class AppController implements IAppController {
    }

    angular.module("test", [
        "ui.router"
    ]).run(["$rootScope", "$state",
        function ($rootScope, $state) {
            // Secure routes
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                if ("login" === toState.name) {
                    return;
                }

                let authorized = toState.data ? toState.data.authorization : false;

                if (!securityService.isAuthenticated && authorized !== true) {
                        $state.go("login");
                }
            });
        }]).component("root", new AppComponent())
        .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) => {
            "ngInject";
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/xyz");
            $stateProvider
                .state("login", {
                    url: "/login",
                    templateUrl: "scripts/components/login/login.html"
                });
        });
}
```

**P.S.**
I use Angular 1.6 with TypeScript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is as simple, as blocking the further execution of the event with `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if ("login" === toState.name) {
                return;
            }

            let authorizationRequired = toState.data ? toState.data.authorization : true;

            if (!securityService.isAuthenticated && authorizationRequired) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go("login");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ui-router you should be using $state.go('state_name')

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, $state, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                if ("login" === toState.name) {
                    return;
                }

                let authorized = toState.data ? toState.data.authorization : false;

                if (!securityService.isAuthenticated && authorized !== true) {
                    $state.go("login");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you inject $state?  Is 'login" the name of your login state?  Are there any errors in your developer console?

Comment: I injected `$state` and I don't get any error notifications on the console. I put a breakpoint, see this call and than happends nothing. I think there is something, that intercepts the call after I do `$state.go()` and redirects to the state again. Due to the fact that the application is pretty small, I could not find any interceptors, or watches, which could cause such a weird situation.

Comment: Without more code it will be impossible to troubleshoot further.  The above will correctly navigate to the "login" state if that block of the if state is executed, so you can be sure that is working correctly now. But any other redirect logic can't be understood from your code samples.

Comment: See the edit. There is really nothing more than this.

Comment: I don't see securityService defined anywhere.

Comment: `namespace testWeb.services {
    export interface ISecurityService {
        isAuthenticated(): boolean;
    }

    class SecurityService implements ISecurityService {
        public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
            return false;
        }

        public $get(): any {
            return { isAuthenticated: this.isAuthenticated() };
        }
    }

    angular.module("test").provider("securityService", [SecurityService]);
}`

Comment: As I already told, all definitions are correct and Angular can find all services, modules and states. Otherwise I would get a huge error message on the console what is not the case.